# Cannot bash into Vault Server Docker container

Tags: docker, coreos, hashicorp-vault

I have been trying to setup Vault by Harshicorp in server mode via its official docker image. Though the vault server is successfully started I cannot bash into the Vault docker container and even cannot interact. I've used the same docker run command given on the [official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/vault/).

Running `docker logs` to the container only gives the following output.

```
==> Vault server configuration:

                     Cgo: disabled
               Log Level: info
                   Mlock: supported: true, enabled: true
                 Storage: file
                 Version: Vault v0.8.3
             Version Sha: 6b29fb2b7f70ed538ee2b3c057335d706b6d4e36

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:
```

When trying to bash into the docker vault container, I get the following output,

```
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/bin/bash\\\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory\"\n"
```

Couldn't find any thing directing to an issue like this. Is this a known issue and I want to know, what am I doing wrong here?

Note - My Environment is a AWS CoreOS instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vault looks based on `alpine:3.6` this means you do not have `bash` but `sh` as shell.

`docker exec -it CONTAINER sh` should do the Job